# Eclipse Mars not running after installing Lombok

Tags: lombok, eclipse-mars

i Need to use project Lombok into my spring based application. I am using eclipse Marc with Spring Tool Suit Plugin, when i try to install lombok jar it executed well and install the lombok to eclipse i-e adding lombok jar statement into eclipse.ini file and adding jar to root folder of eclipse but after this eclipse stop working means when i restart eclipse it does not start. just shows the eclipse launching screen and quickly hide that,
can anyone help me on that.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

go to eclipse.ini and edit and project clean

```
Eclipse.app/Contents/Eclipse/eclipse.ini.

-vmargs
-javaagent:lombok.jar
```

Comment: how to clean the project before eclipse is started ? you means clean using command line ?

Comment: The problem is mostly due to the incorrect path of the lombok jar file. Considering the jar is present in the Eclipse root directory, `-javaagent:lombok.jar` works as mentioned in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem...if you look in your workspace log file you see the error "java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack". Other answers mention of modifying "lombok.jar" in the eclipse.ini file to include the full path, but for me, this didn't help at all.

I was using Eclipse version 2019-12 and Lombok version 1.16.2.  I was only able to resolve this problem by installing Lombok version 1.18.4 instead of version 1.16.2 *and* upgrading to Eclipse 2022-03.  Only then did Eclipse start without crashing, and now the code builds correctly as well.

Answer (score -1):

Check for lombok.jar path in eclise.ini

My lombok.jar was in -

C:\java,tc\eclipse\lombok.jar

For me, it is because of the wrong folder name inside eclipse.ini

-javaagent:C:\java\,tc\eclipse\lombok.jar

it is \java,tc not \java\,tc
once i updated the right path, eclipse started.